# Moving Hundreds of Folders on a Synology NAS with Excel VBA - Permission Denied Error 70

Tags: excel, vba, nas, synology

When my father passed 6 years ago, he had so many different versions of folders ( photos, family documents, etc. etc. ) that he just kept copying from one computer to another, as he procured more computers. As soon as he bought a new computer, he copied files to that new computer, and left the old one with those files in there - incase his new computer failed. He did the same with hard drives - new hard drive - copy over the files. As time went on, he added new photos or files, etc. When he passed, as I had a Synology NAS at the time, I made the effort to go through each computer, and moved all of those files to the NAS - and I created folders as I went along that contained those files. For instance, I found 44 copies of my brother's wedding in all of his hard drives, computers, etc. I only really care for 1 copy of it.

It's been a sort of to do list item to go through the literal terabytes of folders, files, etc. to remove all of the duplicates. I have gotten for myself a Duplicate File/Folder Cleaner App, as well as paid for a license of ULtrafileSearch Pro. I use the latter to find all of the different folders such as ( Photos - Disneyland, or Photos - Son's Wedding). I use the Duplicate File/Folder Cleaner App to try to find all of the duplicate folders, but this process can take days at times because of how much of a wide variety of folders there are.

I realized there's a potential solution. If I took an export of all of the folders in the NAS, I can use Excel to toggle all of the similar types of folders - and I want some code to try to group these folders together - so that I can make the workflow of finding these cases much easier. But, I run into the Permission Denied - Error Code 70. I obviously have full rights on my PC, it's an Admin account.

```
Sub Move_Rename_Folder(FromPath As String, ToPath As String, RowNum As Integer)
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
'Toggle
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Mover").Range("A" & RowNum).Value = "No" Then
   
    Exit Sub
End If

If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then ' Remove the ends
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then ' Remove the ends
    ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

If fso.FolderExists(ToPath) = True Then
    ToPath = ToPath & " " & RowNum ' Add row Number to make a unique directory
End If

fso.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Mover").Range("E" & RowNum).Value = "YES"

End Sub


Sub MainSub()
 Dim CurrentFrom As Range, CurrentTo As Range, Row As Range

 Set CurrentFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Mover").Range("C4")
 Set CurrentTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Mover").Range("D4")
 Set Row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Mover").Range("B4")

 Dim ToPath As String, FromPath As String, RowNum As Integer
 ToPath = CurrentTo.Value
 FromPath = CurrentFrom.Value
 RowNum = Row.Value
  
  'loop while your current frompath is not empty
 Do While FromPath <> ""
     Call Move_Rename_Folder(FromPath, ToPath, RowNum)
    
     'offsets the cells one row down
     Set CurrentFrom = CurrentFrom.Offset(1, 0)
     Set CurrentTo = CurrentTo.Offset(1, 0)
     Set Row = Row.Offset(1, 0)

     FromPath = CurrentFrom.Value
     ToPath = CurrentTo.Value
     RowNum = Row.Value
    
 Loop
 End Sub
```

I don't want to just to a Search of the folder, and pick all but one that I will delete. Some of the older folders have unique files for some reason.

Comment: Do the source and destination folders have the same drive letter (e.g. moving from C: to C:) or are they different (e.g. from C: to D:)? Using [MoveFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefolder-method) between different volumes only works if the OS supports it

Comment: It's a network share, so like \\Diskstation\Folder1\Folder2 to \\Diskstation\Folder3\Folder4